# How do i have to implement my code to get correct json?

Tags: php, json, chart.js

I'm trying to create a JSON string in PHP to populate a chart (chart.js). How do i have to implement the PHP-Code, that i can consume it? Sorry, i am a PHP newbie and i try to learn it right now...

My dataset:

> name  |  amount  | year
>   NAME1 |      10  | 2019
>   NAME2 |      50  | 2019
>   NAME3 |      70  | 2019
>   NAME4 |      90  | 2019
>   NAME1 |    1410  | 2018
>   NAME2 |    155,3 | 2018
>   NAME3 |      15  | 2018
>   NAME4 |   15315  | 2018

Expected result:

> data: {
>     labels: ['NAME1', 'NAME2', 'NAME3', 'NAME4'],
>     datasets: [
>     {
>         label: '2019',
>         data: [10, 50, 70, 90],
>     },
>     {
>         label: '2018',
>         data: [1410, 155.3, 15, 15315],
>     }]
>   },

Actual code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(QUERY);
if(false === $stmt)
{
    $arr["message"] = $mysqli -> errno . ": " . $mysqli -> error;
}
else
{
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($name, $amount, $year);

    if($stmt)
    {
        while($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you already have an array with the values, just use `json_encode()`?

Comment: `SELECT year,GROUP_CONCAT(amount) as data FROM your_table GROUP BY year ORDER BY year desc` then **$data = ['lables' => ['NAME1', 'NAME2', 'NAME3', 'NAME4'],];** then **$data['datasets'] = the_query_above ** after that **$updated = json_encode($data)**

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an array of your data, then use `json_encode`

So an array like this :

```
$data = [
      'data' => ['labels' => $labels],
      'datasets' => $datasets
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

For $labels and $datasets : it's also array that you can construct with your query results.
Your json will be like this : `{'labels':..., 'datasets': ...}`